# use querySelectorAll on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, dynamic, queryselector

I want to query newly added div having memberCard class call but queryselectorall being static , i am not able to do so .How to resolve this problem?

```
var  elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.memberCard')
function list(){
$.ajax({
    url:`http://localhost:8000/members`,
    type:"GET",
    success:function(members){
      
      members.forEach(member => {
      
        
        // Construct card content
         content = `
        <div class='memberCard'>
          <div style='background-image:url("${member.image}")' class='memberImage'>
          </div>
          <div class='memberDetails josephine-sans'>
            <h5>${member.name}</h5>
            <h6>${member.batch}</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        `;
              container.innerHTML += content;
      });

}
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` only retrieves matching elements that exist at the time it is run so it can't be statically stored and account for future elements as well. Please explain your use case and specific problem in more detail. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

> You can use some hack i guess, update elementsToShow after success;

```
var  elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.memberCard')
    function list(){
    $.ajax({
        url:`http://localhost:8000/members`,
        type:"GET",
        success:function(members){
          
          members.forEach(member => {
          
            
            // Construct card content
             content = `
            <div class='memberCard'>
              <div style='background-image:url("${member.image}")' class='memberImage'>
              </div>
              <div class='memberDetails josephine-sans'>
                <h5>${member.name}</h5>
                <h6>${member.batch}</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
            `;
            container.innerHTML += content;
            elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.memberCard')
          });
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Event delegation and set the querySelector on the parent element.
This is an example :

```
<div id="button-container"></div>

// event is added for the parent of #submit-button
document.querySelector("#button-container").addEventListener('click', 
function(e) {
    if(e.target.id == 'submit-button') {
    alert('CLICKED');
    }
});

// #submit-button is dynamically created
document.querySelector("#button-container").innerHTML = '<button id="submit- 
button">Submit</button>';

// click on #submit-button will now work
document.querySelector("#submit-button").click();
```

I suggesst you try to change your code , so you can use it this way.